# Linux terminal command for tracing threads and system calls in a process

Tags: linux, terminal, system-calls, trace

How can I trace the threads / systems calls in a process if the process id is known?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For system calls, you can use [`strace(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) and it supports attaching to live processes.  You just need to figure out the process/thread id.

Comment: Thanks for your reply